# Create Geometric Network Geodatabase Failed

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geometric-network, arcgis-water-utilities

I recently attempted to run the Create Geometric Network Geodatabase tool which is part of a water outage template download and process offered via the ArcGIS Solutions Deployment Tool within ArcGIS Pro. The tool will run almost to completion but then fail immediately at the end.

Clearly this is missing from the AcrPy module but I'm confused as to why?

The following is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 235, in execute
  File "<string>", line 293, in run
  File "Y:\SYSTEM_SUPPORT\PILOT\Water_Outage_Template\Water_Outage_Template\WaterOutageComponents\Tools\ToolData\gnsolutions\publish.py", line 237, in main
    gn = self.create_network()
  File "Y:\SYSTEM_SUPPORT\PILOT\Water_Outage_Template\Water_Outage_Template\WaterOutageComponents\Tools\ToolData\gnsolutions\publish.py", line 99, in create_network
    result = arcpy.CreateGeometricNetwork_management(in_feature_dataset=self.dataset,
AttributeError: module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'CreateGeometricNetwork_management'
 Failed to execute (CreateGeometricNetworkGDB).
```

Comment: The tool is [not available in Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm): "Geometric networks are a read-only dataset in ArcGIS Pro. The capability to manage, model, and analyze network systems for water, gas, electric, telecom, sewer, storm water, and other utilities has been replaced by the Utility Network."

Comment: @BERA Your comment looks like it would suffice as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information

Comment: It does seem very odd for a solution produced/supplied by Esri, for ArcGIS Pro, to contain tools that don't run/exist in Pro.  Even the documentation says it's run in Pro

Comment: Ah - after a bit of a dig, it appears the geoprocessing tools are designed to be run in ArcMap (rather than pro) with a Standard or Advanced license.  See [Water Outage - System Requirements](https://solutions.arcgis.com/water/help/water-outage/get-started/system-requirements.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The tool is [not available in Pro:](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm) "Geometric networks are a read-only dataset in ArcGIS Pro. The capability to manage, model, and analyze network systems for water, gas, electric, telecom, sewer, storm water, and other utilities has been replaced by the [Utility Network](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/utility-network/what-is-a-utility-network-.htm)."